# How to trap interrupt signal using a shell script while editing a file in vi editor which has been opened using the same shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, vi

I am trying to write a shell script which helps me to run and edit java files easily with just one click. I mean the script takes the java filename as argument and then provides three different options for the subsequent action. I need to click one of them and accordingly the work is done. I am using bash shell. I am providing the code I have written, then I will quote my query.

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ $# -eq 0 -o $# -gt 1 ] ; then
    echo "Provide single filename"
    exit
fi

file="$1"
if echo "$file" | grep ".java$" >/dev/null ; then
    file=`expr "$file" : '\(.*\).java'`
fi
file=`echo "$file" | tr -d '.'`
file_with_ext=$file.java

response=`kdialog --radiolist "What do you want to do?" 1 "Run Program" on 2 "Open with vi" off 3 "Open with vi and then Run" off`

if [ -z $response ] ; then
    exit
fi

if [ $response -eq 2 -o $response -eq 3 ] ; then
    if [ ! -s "$file_with_ext" ] ; then
        initcode="public class $file{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
    }
}
"
        echo "$initcode" > $file_with_ext
    fi
    vi $file_with_ext
fi

if [ $response -eq 1 -o $response -eq 3 ] ; then
    javac $file_with_ext
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        java $file_with_ext 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        java $file
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Now I want to add some more functionality to this script. I want that whenever I press some specific combination of keys, the script executes the java program (after compilation) and gives the output in some other terminal. I could have done it easily if there was no text editor involved. But since I am editing the java file in the vi editor, when I am using any Interrupt key, it is not being trapped by the shell script but taken as a command by the vi editor.

Is there a way I can achieve the desired result ?

Any kind of help or guidance will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: example:
 trap clean_up 2 3 14 15;
clean_up () {
  /bin/rm -f rr tt ss channels
}

Comment: @Cinaed I did not get your point. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: To trap the signal, you need call a trap, supply a function to execute when the signal is trapped, and define the signals to be trapped. See https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-trap-command. Shell works the same way. I don't really understand your problem, but your script has no trap defined so it can't  trap the signal - hence my comment.